# Can I open a specific version's mod?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods, wynncraft

I'm trying to download a client-side mod called Wyntills which is a 1.12 mod. I have 1.19 mods in the mod folder, is there a way to only open Wyntills?

Comment: What do you mean by open the mod? Open the game with only that mod loaded? My best guess would be to remove all other mods temporarilly.

Comment: Voting to leave this question open. As per community consensus at the meta posts: [Minecraft crash questions should be made off-topic: yes/no?](//meta.arqade.com/q/10390), [Why just ban Minecraft modding tech support?](//meta.arqade.com/q/10568), [What exactly is technical support?](//meta.arqade.com/q/11015) and [Update the off-topic reason for "Technical support for non-vanilla Minecraft" in the help-center](https://meta.arqade.com/q/13542), only *crash* issues and other technical issues related to *running* modded Minecraft are off-topic. Outside of those, modded issues are on-topic.

Comment: @galacticninja I agree, but it still requires more details..

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible.

You need a third-party launcher that can handle **multiple instances** of Minecraft seperately. One example is the open source project [Prism Launcher](https://github.com/PrismLauncher/PrismLauncher) which I will use for explaining.

How it works is that each created instance has its own .minecraft folder, you log in with your Microsoft account like the Vanilla launcher and it fetches the required files automatically.
[image: The prism launcher menu, showing two instances of Minecraft.]

Once an instance is created, for which in your case you would need to create a 1.19 instance and a 1.12 instance, you can explore the instance files using the folders dropdown.

[image: A dropdown menu with two options, View Instance Folder and View Central Mods Folder.]

You can then freely explore both instances seperately, change settings seperately and install mods seperately in their respective mods folders.
[image: Windows File Explorer with two seperately named folders of Minecraft instances.]

As you can see, my Fabric 1.19.2 instance has its own .minecraft folder.
[image: An instance with the .minecraft folder visible]

Any launcher that offers multiple instancing will work, but always use caution when downloading files from the Internet. Third-Party launchers are not endorsed by Mojang.

Comment: another option is MultiMC